# azure specify where output of the task to put

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am using `vue.js` and `webpack` within it.  I also use `azure pipeline yaml` in my project.

On azure, I have `build` variables which means that variables are created on azure. In there, I have:

```
- script: |
    npm run production
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging'))
  env:
    some_var: 'production'
  displayName: 'Build And Test Staging'
```

in my webpack, output directory is `dist` folder. Now what I need is I need to add the same script as above in my same pipeline, but have `some_var` different.  So it means that when I uplaod my project, it builds the project two times with different variables. The problem this causes is that both of them will end up having `dist` folder and the last one that runs will override it.

I need to tell azure pipeline yaml where to put `dist` folder for each `script`. I don't want to touch my webpack config(I know how that could make it possible). Is there something I can put for each `script` section to specify where to put `dist`folder? and Note: If it's possible, I want it to create that directory too . So having 2 scripts would give me these:

- `firstScriptFolderOutput/dist`
- `SecondScriptFolderOutput/dist`

I'd easily use those in my `publishartifacts` task after that.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to tell azure pipeline yaml where to put dist folder for each
>   script. I don't want to touch my webpack config(I know how that could
>   make it possible)

Since you don't want to touch and modify the webpack config, I'm afraid the script can't do what you want to change the output folder by passing parameter.

The `dist` folder is the default output folder of webpack, if you want something like:

```
firstScriptFolderOutput/dist
SecondScriptFolderOutput/dist
```

As a workaround, consider adding corresponding scripts that executes `mkdir + xcopy` commands below your npm scripts to make your own folder structure.

```
- script: |
    npm run production
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging'))
  env:
    some_var: 'production'
  displayName: 'Build And Test Staging'

One script to create `firstScriptFolderOutput` folder(mkdir) and copy files from ./dist to `firstScriptFolderOutput/dist`

- script: |
    npm run production
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging'))
  env:
    some_var: 'xxx'
  displayName: 'Build And Test Staging'

One script to create `secondScriptFolderOutput` folder(mkdir) and copy files from ./dist to `firstScriptFolderOutput/dist`
```